# Get connectionstring from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key1"]` in **settings.designer.cs** file. It's working fine in the development but after I moved all the **.dll** files into production it is not working.

In `web.config` file I added app settings in development and production both. What is the problem?

Code from settings.designer.cs file

```
get
{
  return WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
  //return (AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
  //return ((string)(this["ConnectionString"])); 
}
```

I tried all three return statements. 3rd return is working fine in both dev & prod but it is not rendering from web.config.

Code in web.config

```
<add key="ConnectionString" value="connection string values are given here">
```

Comment: Does the AppSettings["key1"] exists in your release web.config file?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail please like can you provide a snippet of your config file with the key in and how you are using it in code

Comment: Have you possibly forgotten to put the setting into the release web.config? You need to be a bit more informative with regards to your current setup.

Comment: thanks for ur valuable replies

Comment: till i have same problem

Comment: Do you need AppSettings, ConnectionStrings or design-time Settings?

Comment: Give your question a **meaningful** title please!

Answer (score 1):

**Don't** use `WebConfigurationManager`.

---

Use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]` instead to read key-value pair kept in Web.config, e.g.:

```
<configuration>
    <appSetttings>
        <add key="key1" value="value1" />
    </appSetttings>
</configuration>
```

and `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name"].ConnectionString` to read connection string, e.g.:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="name" connectionString="value1" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @SureshD: What is your problem exactly, what error do you get? And what type of is `this`?

Answer (score -2):

You have to add configuration setting (`connectionstring`) to last execution program config file.